# How to turn columns into rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table like this in mySql Database. this is an employee attendance table

```
Status    Date
P      2021-01-06
A      2021-01-08
P      2021-01-09
P      2021-01-10
A      2021-01-18
P      2021-01-17
```

I want this table in following format.

```
2021-01-06     2021-01-08    2021-01-09    2021-01-10     2021-01-18    2021-01-17
    P              A             P             P               A            P
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: so what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter, what have you researched? and if it is so urgent: have you considered *paying* someone?

Comment: What you seek is known as a [tag:pivot].

Comment: Why is there a C# tag? Do you need to do the transphormation in C#?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I'm new to C# and mysql I don't have any idea how to do that. I use pivot table query but it not work accurately. please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when date = '2021-01-06' then status end) as x_20210106,
       max(case when date = '2021-01-07' then status end) as x_20210107,
       . . . 
from t;
```